# How can I get in_array() to work with multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

What am I doing wrong in the code below?

```
print_r(array_values($haystack));
```

returns the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => album2 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => album3 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Album 1 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => jopie99 ) [4] => Array ( [name] => kopie3 ) [5] => Array ( [name] => test56 ) [6] => Array ( [name] => rob7 ) ) testArray ( [0] => Array ( [name] => album2 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => album3 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Album 1 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => jopie99 ) [4] => Array ( [name] => kopie3 ) [5] => Array ( [name] => test56 ) [6] => Array ( [name] => rob7 ) )
```

Now I have the following code:

```
$needle = 'album3';

if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) {   
    //do something 
}
```

At least the needle can be found somewhere in the haystack, but apparently not with the if statement given. Can someone help me out?

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using multidimentional array. you can use below method.

```
$needle = 'album3';
foreach($haystack as $h){
  if ( $h['name'] == $needle ){
     // do something...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `array_column` along with `in_array` as

**Note : PHP>=5.5**

```
if(in_array($needle,array_column($arr,'name'))){
   //your code
}
```

or you can alternatively use as

```
if(in_array(['name' => $needle],$arr)){
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Just go through each array value with [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and check if the needle is equals the value. If yes simply set the result to true.

```
<?php

    $needle = 'album3';
    $arr = [["album1"],["album2"],["album4"],["album3"]];
    $result = FALSE;

    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k)use($needle, &$result){
        if($v == $needle)
            $result = TRUE;
    });

    var_dump($result);

?>
```

This works with every array no matter how many dimensions it has.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this using strict checking:

```
if (in_array($needle, $haystack, true))
```

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for more info.